# Git repository not working (git keeps removing HEAD file)

Tags: git

My git repository suddenly became corrupted (possibly after updating Sublime with some files from the repo still open). When I tried to display git status, I got this error message:

`fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

When I looked inside the .git folder, the HEAD file was missing. I tried to recreate the file with the command

`echo 'ref: refs/heads/master' > ../.git/HEAD`

but nothing happened, so I tried to create the file manually, but it got renamed to
*HEAD (VAVRIK-PC's conflicted copy 2021-05-27)*. Later I tried to disconnect my PC from the internet (my repo is linked to GitHub) and repeated previous steps. This time I managed to recreate the HEAD file and stage some changes for commit, but when I tried to commit the changes, I got the following error message:

```
error: invalid object 100644 91e213ecdea4b589613a7cd7dc078bc501bc039d for 'cascade_flux/.gitignore'
error: invalid object 100644 91e213ecdea4b589613a7cd7dc078bc501bc039d for 'cascade_flux/.gitignore'
error: Error building trees
```

After I turned on the Wi-Fi again, the HEAD file disappeared. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: It sounds like you've put your git repo in a directory synchronised with a cloud storage like Dropbox or Google Drive. That's generally a bad idea - those are designed for synchronising _documents_, but a git repo is more like the database for a running application.

Comment: @IMSoP Yeah, my git repo was actually in the Dropbox folder. Now I have moved it outside and can change the HEAD file without problems. However, I still can't commit the changes and keep getting the same error.

Comment: Dropbox has corrupted your git checkout. Your best bet is probably just to clone a new copy from GitHub, unless you've got commits you haven't pushed up yet.

Comment: @IMSoP Ok, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a way, you're getting lucky here: when Dropbox corrupts a Git repository, the corruption is sometimes not visible until you've already lost some work irrecoverably.

In general, Git needs *full control* over its databases (in the `.git` directory).  Never put them in a shared space, whether with Dropbox or iCloud or any other file synchronization software.  In some very specific situations, where you know what you're doing and are sure Git isn't modifying stuff *in* the directory, it's OK to duplicate the directory via some sort of network or other copying software.  But Git is overly sensitive to the kinds of changes these things make when they auto-resolve conflicting changes, so it's way too easy for sharing software to make a mess of the Git databases.